# Why is my dat/output file empty?

Tags: c++, binary

I tried running my code. no error but there's is no output in the data file itself when I reinterpret cast.
May I know what is missing?
Thank you.
I need the dat file to take in all the input provided by the cin

Use securing confined his shutters. Delightful as he it acceptance an solicitude discretion reasonably. Carriage we husbands advanced an perceive greatest. Totally dearest expense on demesne ye he. Curiosity excellent commanded in me. Unpleasing impression themselves to at assistance acceptance my or. On consider laughter civility offended oh.

Spot of come to ever hand as lady meet on. Delicate contempt received two yet advanced. Gentleman as belonging he commanded believing dejection in by. On no am winding chicken so behaved. Its preserved sex enjoyment new way behaviour. Him yet devonshire celebrated especially. Unfeeling one provision are smallness resembled repulsive.

In alteration insipidity impression by travelling reasonable up motionless. Of regard warmth by unable sudden garden ladies. No kept hung am size spot no. Likewise led and dissuade rejoiced welcomed husbands boy. Do listening on he suspected resembled. Water would still if to. Position boy required law moderate was may.

```
struct task
{
    char title[MAX]; // Eg. Assignment ,Exam,Test
    int weight; // Weightage of the task
    int fullmark; // Upon
    float mark; // Obtained marks
};

struct Subject
 {
    char subCode[MAX]; // CSCI103 MATH STAT
    char subTitle[MAX]; // Full title of subject
    int noTask; // No. of task for following struct
    task Task[MAX]; // Array of tasks
    float finalMark; // Final overall mark for subject
    Grade finalGrade; // Grade for subject
 };

int main()
{
    fstream afile;

afile.open ("test.dat", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);

int totalWeight = 0;
Subject S;

if(!afile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file,please check" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

cout << "------------------" << endl
    << "Subject adding system" << endl
    << "------------------" << endl << endl;

cout << "Subject Code: ";
cin >> S.subCode;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100,'\n');

cout << "Subject Name: ";
cin.getline (S.subTitle, MAX);

cout << "No of assessment tasks: ";
cin >> S.noTask;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100,'\n');

cout << endl;

// Loop for binary file
for(int i = 1;i<=S.noTask;i++)
{
    cout << "Task " << i << " Information" << endl
        << "\t Title: ";
    cin >> S.Task[i].title;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');

    cout << "\t Weight: ";
    cin >> S.Task[i].weight;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');

    cout << "\t Upon: ";
    cin >> S.Task[i].fullmark;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');

    totalWeight +=S.Task[i].weight;
}

cout << endl << "Subject " << S.subTitle << " added to system" << endl
    << "Total weight = " << totalWeight << endl;

afile.write (reinterpret_cast <const char*>(&S), sizeof (S));

afile.close();
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you define `Subject`?

Comment: outside of main function

struct Subject
 {
    char subCode[MAX]; // CSCI103 MATH STAT
    char subTitle[MAX]; // Full title of subject
    int noTask; // No. of task for following struct
    task Task[MAX]; // Array of tasks
    float finalMark; // Final overall mark for subject
    Grade finalGrade; // Grade for subject
 };

Comment: You should edit the main post

Answer (score 0):

You open the file with the flag `std::ios::in` (therefore you open it for reading), and try to write to it with `afile.write(&S, sizeof(S))`

If you want to write to the file you can either:

1. Open it with `std::ios::out` insteand of `std::ios::in`
2. Use an `std::ofstream` instead of an `std::fstream` and omit the std::ios::in/out flag

Also, in the future, try to reduce the code in question to the minimum to understand you problem.

Comment: oh my god cant believe i missed that.Thank you

Comment: What's the difference with writing with reinterpret cast?

Comment: I just ommitted it for brevity. You will have to cast it to `const char*` in actual code though, reinterpret_cast is a good choice for that here